# Deleted answer. Do you think my logic is flawed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32062/who-are-all-these-catholics) contained:
"
The question is seeking an answer to who all these Catholics are - when the belief is in the One, Holy, Catholic and Apostolic Church, - **and how does THE CATHOLIC CHURCH** view those who say identify themselves as Trads, Liberal, etc.?"

Answer closed because:
This question asks for an explanation of terms and needs to be answered with an explanation of the term **from the perspective of the people that use them!**

My opinion:
It asks for what the Catholic Church says about people who use those terms.  An answer from Pope Leo XIII is reasonable.

Comment: Just so we get the terminology right, your answer was *deleted* not closed. Only questions can be closed, and this one is on the verge of it (though I declined to mod close it earlier in the day as it's very borderline but probably OK if the community wants to keep it)

Comment: @waxeagle The question should probably be broken up I agree.

Answer (score 4):

Whether you agree with them or not—whether you think the terms are legitimate and should be used or not—whether any one of the groups involved uses any of the terms or rejects them is irrelevant to the question. **The terms exist.** What they mean to the people that use them, specifically who they refer to and in what context the terms are meaningful is the only way to answer this question.

This is equivalent to the handling of any other question on this site. A question such as "Who are the Anabaptists and how are they different from Baptists?" may *not* be answered with a post saying "All denominations are wrong, we shouldn't use such labels." Of course there are people that think the latter but that view is irrelevant to the question.

The question does not ask just what the RCC position is in regard to each of those labels, much less what Sedevacantist think the true answer is. It asks what all the terms are about in relation to each-other. Posts that do not attempt to disambiguate all the terms and somehow relate them to each-other in a way that makes their usage comprehensible are invalid.

Comment: "The question does not ask what the RCC position is in regard to each of those labels."  Yes it does.  Its in BOLD.  That's my point.  Here it is again.  "and how does THE CATHOLIC CHURCH view those ..."

Comment: @apocalypse_info_click_here Sorry, I was missing the word "just" in there. You can't skip over dealing with all the labels just by lumping them all as heretics. That doesn't explain to anybody what the whole labeling thing is about. At best your answer would work as one facet to a multi-part answer that broke down the different contexts.